# Calculate an integral using the result of a similar integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I've to calculate an integral , using the result of a similar integral.
I have:

$$ \int \sin^3 dx = -\frac {1}{3} \cos x(2+\sin^2x)
$$

I need this result for calculating this :

$$ \sin^3(5x+3)dx
$$

I don't understand how I can use the previous result, there is a simple way to substitute the argument of the $$ \sin^3() $$ ?

Comment: $u=5x+3,\ x=\dfrac{u-3}5,\ \mathrm dx=\dfrac15\ \mathrm du$.

Comment: $$\int \sin^3 (5x+3)\, dx=\frac{1}{5}\int \sin^3 (5x+3)\, d(5x+3)$$

$$=\frac{1}{5}\left(-\frac{1}{3}\cos (5x+3)(2+\sin^2 (5x+3))\right)+C$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int { sin^{ 3 }(5x+3)dx } =\frac { 1 }{ 5 } \int { \sin ^{ 3 }{ \left( 5x+3 \right) d } \left( 5x+3 \right)  } =-\frac { 1 }{ 15 } cos\left( 5x+3 \right) \left( 2+sin^{ 2 }\left( 5x+3 \right)  \right) +C$$

Comment: I don't understand the $$ \frac {1}{5} $$

Comment: By substitution as Kenny Lau commented you will get same asnwer,i have written it directly

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use a new variable and write the integral accordingly, as follows.

$v=5x+3,\ x=\dfrac{v-3}5,\ \mathrm dx=\dfrac15\ \mathrm dv$

$$\int { sin^{ 3 }(5x+3)dx } =\int { \sin ^{ 3 }{ \left( v\right) \dfrac15\ \mathrm dv}  } =\frac{1}{5}\int { \sin ^{ 3 }{ \left( v\right) dv}  }=-\frac { 1 }{ 15 } cos\left( v \right) \left( 2+sin^{ 2 }\left( v \right)  \right) +C=-\frac { 1 }{ 15 } cos\left( 5x+3 \right) \left( 2+sin^{ 2 }\left( 5x+3 \right)  \right) +C$$